# Apriori Bound of $L^2$-norm of ODE

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, lp-spaces

I'm trying to solve this exercise.

[image]

[image]

I solved the points (a) and (b) but I'm not able to solve the point (c). I'm trying to proceed in this way:

By following the hint we have $uu''=uf$, then by using the relation $(uu')'=(u')^2+uu''$, we get 
$$\int_0^1(uu')' \, dx=\int_0^1(u')^2\, dx+\int_0^1uu'' \, dx.$$

Since $u(0)=u(1)=0$ and $u''=f$, we get $$\vert\vert u'\vert\vert_2^2=-\int_0^1uf \, dx.$$ Now I don't know how to proceed. Can you help me?

**NB:** Here $\vert\vert \bullet\vert\vert_p^p=\int_0^1(\bullet)^p$.

Comment: It might be useful to show that $$- \int_{0}^{1} uf dx = \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \| u \|_{2}^{2} + \| f \|_{2}^{2} - \| u + f\|_{2}^{2} \bigg)$$ noting that $\| u + f\|_{2}^{2} \ge 0$

Comment: It could be a good suggestion...maybe combined to some inequality of the type $\int_0^\epsilon \vert g\vert \, dx<\epsilon \int_0^1\vert g\vert \, dx$...

Comment: Use Cauchy-Schwarz and geometric-quadratic mean inequalties.

Comment: Can you expand you suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus we can write (here we use that $u(0)=0$)
$$
u(x)=\int_0^x u'(t)\,dt.
$$
Thus, by the triangle inequality,
$$
\int_0^1 u(x)^2\,dx=\int_0^1\Bigl(\int_0^x u'(t)\,dt\Bigr)^2\,dx\leq \int_0^1\Bigl[\int |u'(t)|\,dt\Bigr]^2\,dx
$$
Using Cauchy--Schwarz inequality on the inner integral, we get
$$
\int_0^1 u(x)^2\,dx\leq \int_0^1\Bigl[\int_0^x 1^2\,dt\int_0^x |u'(t)|^2\,dt\Bigr]\,dx.
$$
Calculating the first of the inner integrals and bounding the second one when we replace the bound $x$ by $1$, we find that
$$
\|u\|_2^2=\int_0^1 u(x)^2\,dx\leq \int_0^1 x \,dx\cdot \int_0^1|u'(t)|^2\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\|u'\|_2^2.\tag{*}
$$
Multiplying $u''=f$ with $-u$ and integrating by parts (remembering the Dirichlet conditions), and using Cauchy--Schwarz again, we find that
$$
\|u'\|_2^2=\int_0^1 (u'(x))^2\,dx=\int_0^1 u''(-u)\,dx
=\int_0^1 f(-u)\,dx\leq \|f\|_2\|u\|_2.\tag{**}
$$
Combinging (*) and (**) we find the inequality we look for,
$$
\|u'\|_2^2\leq \|f\|_2\|u\|_2\leq \|f\|_2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\|u'\|_2.
$$
Just divide by $\|u'\|_2$ and square.